# How to set an encoding for the JavaDoc in gradle?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, gradle, javadoc

I have written Java-Classes with JavaDoc-commands that contain special characters like `äöü`. I generate the JavaDoc using a gradle build-file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

and the in the commandline: `gradle javadoc`.

The encoding of the original files is UTF-8. The encoding of the JavaDoc files is also UTF-8. But there is no hint in the HTML-sources, that the files are UTF-8. Thats why my browser always thinks it is `ISO-8859`.

How can I tell javadoc (via gradle) to also add `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` to the source codes, when generating the JavaDoc?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll want to set the javadoc [charset option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#charset).

```
javadoc {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Comment: I am confused as the option is named `encoding` instead of `charSet` in gradle

Comment: @ArneBurmeister indeed, options.encoding = 'UTF-8' worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using gradle 2.13+ and neither Mark's answer nor Arne's comment works for me.

However, I could fix it via `addStringOption()`:

```
javadoc {
    options.addStringOption("charset", "UTF-8")
}
```

See gradles [Javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html) docs and the [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#charset) option from Javadoc for more details.

Comment: I've confirmed your solution for `Gradle` version `2.14.1`, Only works with your approach.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Gradle 2.1,and found the following configuration works for me .

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me works this:

```
javadoc {
    options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
}
```

In Gradle 3.3